# Make the width of a RectTransform object adjust to the size of its child objects by expanding on one side only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

In the game, UI objects (buttons) are dynamically created, they can be added and removed, the parent object should adjust to their size and only grow to the right, I used anchor but it still increases in two sides

Video of adding objects and their propereties: https://youtu.be/GlIy7Xp4YMw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a note about the terminology:** The issue that you are facing is with your implementation of the HorizontalLayoutGroup (I hope that this note will also increase the post visibility for people using search engines to find a similar solution)

You mentioned that you've used the anchor, but the this is not an anchor releated issue, because you are dealing with expansion to a specific direction; Anchors only give your object a range to expand to, so they can control if the object can expand on the x or on the y axis. you locked both anchors to the same position so you're not giving the object a range of freedom in that regard anyway (you're using the LayourGroup for that), so it's completley unrelated to them.

**Solution:**

What you want to do is to change the **Pivot** to be at x: 0 y: 0.5
(all the way to the left),

it'll make the RectTransform expand **only to the right**, as expansion direction is relative to the pivot.